# Testing inner function in Angular through jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, closures, angular-test

So I am defining an inner function and assigning it to a class variable so that I can use it again.
That's cuz I want access to the the parent function's arguments but dont want any other method of the class to have access over that data

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-report-topup',
  templateUrl: './report-topup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./report-topup.component.scss'],
})
export class ReportTopupComponent implements OnInit {
 
  loadReports: (pageNum, pageSize) => void;
  reportDataSource: ReportDataSource;
  currentPageDetails: { index: number; size: number } = { index: 0, size: 5 };

  constructor(public topupHttpService: TopupHttpService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource(this.topupHttpService);
  }

  onReportTopupSearchFormSubmit(formData: ReportTopupSearch) {
  
    this.loadReports = (pageNum, pageSize) => {
      this.reportDataSource.loadReports();
    };

    this.loadReports(0, this.currentPageDetails.size);
    this.setCurrentPageDetails(0 , this.currentPageDetails.size);
  }
```

The code works fine but when I go to test it I start getting problems .
this is my spec.ts function :

```
 it('should call load Reports and setCurrentPageDetails on form submit', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'setCurrentPageDetails');
  
    const reportFormData: ReportTopupSearch = {
      company: 'ABC',
      dateFrom: '2021-01-01',
      dateTo: '2021-01-02',
      status: 'new',
    };

    component.onReportTopupSearchFormSubmit(reportFormData);
    
    expect(component.loadReports).toBeDefined();
    expect(component.loadReports).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.setCurrentPageDetails).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

1. If I try to use  `spyOn` from jasmine , the test runner gives an Error saying this :
   [image: loadReports() not a method]
2. If I try to use `jasmine.createSpy` , like this :

`component.loadReports = jasmine.createSpy('load reports spy' , () => {});` I get the error "Expected spy but got a function" :
[image]

I am not sure how to solve this and test that component.loadReports() have been called .
While the spy for setCurrentPageDetails() method works fine because its a method of the class.
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `loadReports()` method's signature, but you are not providing any implementation. When `jasmine` tries to set an spy, it expects a function so it fails to set the spy.

Add an implementation for `loadReports()` so jasmine can spy on it using this syntax:

```
spyOn(component, 'loadReports');
```

Comment: Ok , so I tried to declare loadReports and assign it an empty function , 
```
 loadReports: (pageNum, pageSize) => void = ({} , {})=>{};
```
and added the spy like you mentioned , 
still getting error and test case failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are implementing the `loadReports` and call it immediately, there is no way to be able to spy on it like this, `SpyOn` needs the implementation:

- if you spyOn `loadReports` **before** calling `onReportTopupSearchFormSubmit` it will complain that `loadReports` is not a function.
- if you spyOn `loadReports` **after** calling `onReportTopupSearchFormSubmit`, it is too late since the `loadReports` has already been called.

My suggestion is to separate `onReportTopupSearchFormSubmit` into two methods:

- first method to dynamically implement the `loadReports`
- second method will use the previous implementation and add the rest of the logic there `this.loadReports(0, this.currentPageDetails.size); this.setCurrentPageDetails(0 , this.currentPageDetails.size);`